# HTTP POST request message is not received every time in Mulle when using CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors, mule, cross-domain, anypoint-studio

I have a set of UI screens written in Angularjs which steps through an example customer order
1. gets the customer
2. gets the products
3. creates the order

The UI and Mule are configured for Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) and the HTTP GET calls work correctly but the HTTP POST request shows in the Chrome DevTools Network console as an error and has been cancelled.

When I run Mule in debug mode, the HTTP POST request is not received every time from the UI and most often I have to run the 3 customer order steps twice to see the POST request trigger the create order workflow which appears to complete successfully when triggered.  Everytime though the POST call shows as cancelled in Chrome DevTools.

Does anyone know what may be causing this behaviour and how to get the POST message to trigger the Mule workflow everytime?

I am not sure if the OPTIONS message that is sent as part of the CORS procedure is then not triggering the POST because of something in the Mule code and the reason it works second time is because the OPTIONS reply has been cached so it sends the POST request straight away or whether there is something else.

XML Flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:cors="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors" xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cors/current/mule-cors.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <apikit:config name="test-order-config" raml="test-order.raml" consoleEnabled="true" consolePath="console" doc:name="Router">
        <apikit:flow-mapping resource="/orders/order" action="post" content-type="application/json" flow-ref="post:/orders/order:test-order-config"/>    
    </apikit:config>

    <cors:config name="Cors_Configuration" doc:name="Cors Configuration">
        <cors:origins>
            <cors:origin url="*">
                <cors:methods>
                    <cors:method>POST</cors:method>
                    <cors:method>DELETE</cors:method>
                    <cors:method>PUT</cors:method>
                    <cors:method>GET</cors:method>
                    <cors:method>OPTIONS</cors:method>
                </cors:methods>
                <cors:headers>
                    <cors:header>Content-Type</cors:header>
                </cors:headers>
            </cors:origin>
        </cors:origins>
    </cors:config>

    <flow name="test-order-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Experience_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cors:validate config-ref="Cors_Configuration" publicResource="true" acceptsCredentials="false" doc:name="CORS Validate"/>
        <apikit:router config-ref="test-order-config" doc:name="APIkit Router"/>               
        <exception-strategy ref="test-order-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="set-access-control-allow">
        <set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" doc:name="Set Access Control Allow Origin"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="false" doc:name="Set Access Control Allow Credentials"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" doc:name="Set Access Control Allow Methods"/>
        <set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,origin,authorization,accept,client-security-token" doc:name="Set Access Control Allow Headers"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="get:/products:test-order-config">
        <set-payload value="#['{ &quot;getProducts&quot;: { &quot;productsList&quot;: [{ &quot;productId&quot;: &quot;001&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;test_product1&quot;}]}}']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="set-access-control-allow" doc:name="set-access-control-allow"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="get:/customer/{customerId}:test-order-config">
        <set-payload value="#['{&quot;getCustomer&quot;:{&quot;customerId&quot;:&quot;1234567890&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;MR&quot;,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;John&quot;}}']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="set-access-control-allow" doc:name="set-access-control-allow"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="post:/orders/order:test-order-config">
        <set-payload value="#['{&quot;createOrder&quot;:{&quot;orderId&quot;:&quot;8a493ecd-e842-4ca2-b33b-a03aa9136673&quot;,&quot;success&quot;:true}}']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="set-access-control-allow" doc:name="set-access-control-allow"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

    <apikit:mapping-exception-strategy name="test-order-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping">
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="404">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotFoundException"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Resource not found&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="405">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.MethodNotAllowedException"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Method not allowed&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
        <apikit:mapping statusCode="400">
            <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.BadRequestException"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Bad request&quot; }" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </apikit:mapping>
    </apikit:mapping-exception-strategy>

</mule>
```

Chrome DevTools shows the Request Headers as provisional in the POST call it shows as cancelled even though sometimes the request is received by Mule and processed correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

HTTP POST call in angularjs code:

```
postContent: function (link, data) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: link,
                headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
                data: angular.toJson(data)
            }).success(function (responseData) {
                //do stuff with response
                var returnData = responseData;
            }).error(function (e) {
                //do stuff with response
                var error = e;
            });
        }
```

Comment: Look in the Console, it should have an error message telling you why the browser canceled the POST request after getting the response to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Hi - I've added a screenshot from the console and there does not appear to be an error.  Is there anywhere else I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `OPTIONS` in the authorized requests :

```
<cors:methods>
    <cors:method>OPTIONS</cors:method>
</cors:methods>
```

**EDIT** the OP also had to delete the `Content-type` header from his `$http` call, this is what all the comments are about.

Comment: I have updated the code (see above) but am still getting the problem where the POST request is not received in Mule everytime and I have to repeat the steps at least (usually) twice to get the POST message to appear in the workflow

Comment: Could you also post a screenshot of the network tab in your browser console ?

Comment: Added screenshots as requested

Comment: Sorry, could you instead post a screenshot of the problematic one ? I should have been more precise, sorry.

Comment: The problem one is the first 2 screenshots which show the order in red and cancelled in the first and then the second shows the headers for it (the other tabs preview, response, timing don't show anything).  The third screenshot shows what looks like a successful order response message from the OPTIONS request message and fourth is what shows in the console tab when I hit the create order button on the UI.   Let me know if I've misunderstood or you need more info.  I can't seem to find anymore errors in Chrome DevTools at the moment.

Comment: No I'm sorry, I just scrolled up and saw only one screenshot, my bad. Why is it that your cancelled request uses a Content-type, and not the accepted one  ?

Comment: I have added the angularjs code for the HTTP POST call in case it helps

Comment: I know content-type was being sent so it was seen as JSON but not sure why it has been separated out from the accepted field.  How could I change it to use the accepted one?  Would that be what is causing the issue?

Comment: Well I honestly don't know, it's very strange. But it's worth taking a look I guess. In your http post call, delete your header and see what happens ?

Comment: I removed the Content Type Header from the HTTP POST call in the angularjs code and it returns success now.  Thanks alot for your help.  Had me scratching my head for the last day or so :)

Comment: Well no problem, but I don't know what happened there. So you're pretty lucky ahah ! I edited my answer to let people know without reading the comments.